# How to insert data from a TXT file into a SQLite database using VBA?

Tags: vba, performance, sqlite, csv

I want to insert a big amount of data from a TXT file into a SQLite database using VBA.

Basically I have already generated my TXT files, but I couldn't find any code or information about how I could insert them automatically into SQLite. Oh yes, and before I got to this point a tried to save the same data directly in SQLite, but it's taking too much time to record all the data, that is spread in more than one database file according to a rule that must be followed.

So, I don't know the exact number, but it's something about 600K records and it's taking a whole day. And once I realised the recording process was much faster when I used TXT files, I want to input this TXT file into the my database, automatically.

As I said I couldn't find anything similar, but I guess it's just connect SQLite and VBA and then send a command to insert a TXT file "X" into a specified database "Y".

But of course, if someone knows how I could record my data faster it would also be a solution, once the reason that I want insert from TXT to SQLite is because from excel (VBA) to SQLite is taking a lot of time. So, that is what I got: VBA -> SQLite (slow); I want: VBA -> TXT -> SQLite; But till the moment I only have: VBA -> TXT.

Comment: How about TXT -> SQLite, and skip VBA altogether? Not familiar with SQLite, but there's gotta be a way to import data from a text file directly? If it's anything like SQL Server, then you could try the *Import/Export Wizard* - in SSMS right-click the database you want to import into, select "import data" from the "tasks" sub-menu.

Comment: That said I'd be curious to see the runs-all-day VBA code. Might be a good idea to put it up for peer review on [codereview.se].

Comment: Thanks Mathieu. The problem is that it would be about 200 or more txt files to input one by one... I want to know how to do this automatically so I can build a loop to do the same to all txt.

Comment: That could be scripted and done with a scheduled PowerShell script... in any case, as it stands your question is *too broad* to be answerable, and will likely end up closed as such. Feel free to [edit] and include your code, but as I said above if the code actually works but is just slow, it's probably best to have it reviewed on CR; Stack Overflow works best for more specific, narrowed-down issues that can be expressed with a [mcve].

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look on CR, thanks.